# gridview with a common Column for few rows possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to display a gridview with a column common for few rows. For Example, i want to show the manager only once in a column for all the employees under that manager? This is in asp.net using c#..

Comment: [This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1053747.aspx/1) has some example code. It only statically sets one cell's `rowspan` but you could use a similar idea to set cell `rowspan`s dynamically as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to merge cells in ASP.net gridview. But you can use Javascript to navigate through the gridview and merge cells.